# Composer exception when installing Zend Framework 2 Skeleton application

Tags: php, macos, zend-framework, zend-framework2, composer-php

I am trying to setup a Zendframework 2.3 application on my MAMP server running MAMP pro 3.0. I am using the instructions on TemplateStock (http://www.templatestock.net/install-zend-framework-2-on-mac-osx-and-mamp/). Installing composer is successful:

```
/Applications/MAMP$ curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -d detect_unicode=off #!/usr/bin/env php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer successfully installed to: /Applications/MAMP/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
```

Then I try to run the  following to install the skeleton project:

```
php composer.phar create-project -sdev --repository-url="https://packages.zendframework.com" zendframework/skeleton-application /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyApp
```

and I get the following output:

```
Installing zendframework/skeleton-application (dev-master 67cbbbf61897831ef1feda323be9845aa7d79682)
  - Installing zendframework/skeleton-application (dev-master master)
    Cloning master

 Created project in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myApp/



  [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                         
  Composer could not find the config file: /Users/shill/.composer/vendor/bin                                                         
  To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section  



create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [package] [directory] [version]
```

Running `php composer.phar diag' returns OK for everything.

The composer.json file in the myApp directory is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
  "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
  "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
  "keywords": [
      "framework",
      "zf2"
  ],
  "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
  "require": {
      "php": ">=5.3.3",
      "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.*"
  }
}
```

## Resolved...Need Super User Permission

```
sudo php composer.phar install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got into troubles by using composer at a certain moment with sudo rights. Now you got the `/Users/shill/.composer.json/` directory owned by root. This caused a failure in the installation of a single project.

You "fixed" this by using sudo for installation of the project itself too. This is not a fix, it just enlarges your problem. What you need to do is to chown all those files to yourself again.

Assumed you're user name is shill:

```
chmod -R shill:shill /Users/shill/.composer.json
chmod -R shill:shill /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myApp
```

Make sure the web server / php worker is able to read files in your myApp directory, but that shouldn't really be difficult.